# Inefficient memory usage in R when turning xml into dataframes

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, for-loop, plyr

I'm trying to figure out, how to stop R from consuming unreasonably much RAM during my script run. My concern is to convert each of 100MB-ish xml files (that are parts of a large 10GB xml) to data frames and then save them as csv files to merge them later. I tried to convert the large xml, had no success though, as it not only crashed R, but the whole system, so it needed to reboot.

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)
library(data.table)

    filelist<-list.files(pattern="origfile\\.\\d*\\.xml")
    #vector with xml names in my working directory
                
    for (i in 1:length(filelist)) {
      data <- xmlParse(filelist[i])
      xml_data <- xmlToList(data)
      df<-ldply(xml_data, rbind)
      fwrite(df, file = paste("newfile",i,".csv",sep=""),row.names = FALSE)
      rm(data,xml_data,df)
      gc()
    }
```

The problem is, every time the for loop starts again, it adds new data without discarding variables that have no use already, even if I delete them explicitly. Sometimes RAM usage drops to 60%, but then grows up again. After it reaches some limit, exception "cannot allocate vector of size x MB" is thrown. PC has 16GB of RAM, but R doesn't seem to need more than 1.5-2GB for one cycle step.

What should be changed in code or what needs to be done in general to prevent reaching RAM limit?

Comment: I think R is not the best (most efficient) tool to convert XML to CSV.

Comment: This is evident for me now, but the main purpose is to pass those data further inside script, that does the rest of required operations. I used splitted xml files instead of the large original to give R at least some chance to proceed, but even this doesn't help as I supposed it would

Comment: It all depends (you didn't show the structure of the XML): You could run an external converter from R.